# Permalink Redirect from /%postname%/ to /%postname%.html in Wordpress Hosted Blog

Tags: wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I've just changed my permalinks from `/%postname%/` to `/%postname%.html`

So, links which are in `/%postname%/` are showing `404` error.

I want to redirect those links to `/%postname%.html` in order to avoid 404 error page.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the permalink settings with extension will effect only in posts, not in pages. In many instances like this I always use this plugin http://www.introsites.co.uk/wordpress/html-on-pages-plugin.html, it is a short plugin and editable, you can change the extension (.html) to many other like: .asp, .shtml, etc.

But please note: if you do an edit to your permalink setting please deactivate the plugin and activated it again when your done. Because if you change the permalink setting and didn't deactivate and activate this plugin all the page will appear as not found.

You can see the plugin stats http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/html-on-pages/stats/ to see how many people used the plugin.